# Exe, created with PyInstaller 3.5, cannot run on end-user's computer

Tags: python, windows-10, exe, pyinstaller

Ive created a simple `PyQT4` scraping program and had generated an `exe` of the program using `pyinstaller-3.5`. I have tested it locally and shared a zip archive with the end user. It was reported that upon launching the `exe` an error pops up stating that

> **"Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have appropriate permissions to access the item."**

I have made sure that this exe is able to run on Windows 7 and Windows 10 workstations, other than the workstation that the program was developed on.

This is a generic Windows error and possibly a common problem when it comes to  shipping exe applications.

What are some known workarounds for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is one scenario where you can run into permissions problems. If you use PyInstaller to create an MSI installer, it will try to install your program into %PROGRAMFILES% and the install directory will have limited write permissions. In this scenario, if your python program tries to do any writes, you will get permissions errors. You should be able to reproduce this problem by installing on your own machine.

I have had this same problem with my own program, and I manually change the permissions on a config.ini file after install. This could probably be automated by a post install script that fires after MSI is finished doing its thing.

Comment: tbh you should probably just avoid writing into your program's install location